# Making time string

Tags: java, format

Is it possible to make a string with 2 double digit numbers with ":" between them so it will look like
04:02? 
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
int h = 4;
int m = 2;
String time = new String(h+":"+m);    
time = String.format("%02d",h+":"+m);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
time = String.format("%02d",h+":"+m);
```

to

```
time = String.format("%02d:%02d", h, m);
```

Also, you can combine line 3/4 into

```
String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", h, m);
```

[Run the code here](http://ideone.com/Tx0A4p)